# ASP.NET MVC different helpers types

Tags: model-view-controller, html-helper

I wonder why classes in Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll such as Facebook, Twitter don't use HtmlHelper? They are still helpers, arn't they?

For some reason they derive from HelperPage. However all their logic resides in static methods.

Can someone explain this to me? If I want to write my own helpers, should I always use extensions over HtmlHelper or do it like in Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll? What are pros and cons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I understand it now.

What I missed is `[GeneratedCode("RazorSingleFileGenerator", "1.0.0.0")]` attribute on the classes. It was likely added by [Razor Single File Generator for MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f28290ce-d987-4f91-b034-707031e10ce6) . My guess these classes was @helpers at first and compiled then.